# Electronic insulation paper, home made alternatives?

Tags: temperature, insulation, mechanical-assembly

I need some electric insulation paper similar to Aramid.

It's to protect lithium batteries which only operate under 200°C in a worst case scenario, and normally less than 70°C, and Aramid can handle 500°C.

Baking paper for the oven is OK at 240°C, and I figure it will be fine to fold some over and use it instead of Aramid.

Do you have better suggestions of common materials that can be used for groups of lithium cells?

Comment: Yellow transformer tape? Won't do 200 degrees for any longer period of time but neither does your batteries.

Comment: Kapton tape....

Comment: Fiberglass cloth...easy to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thermal runaway in Li-ion batteries begins at temperatures around 120-130°C. At this temperature, the passivation layer breaks down, releasing more heat as it breaks, and cell decomposition process becomes self-sustained and irreversible.

[image]

There is really no point in the insulator which can withstand more than 120°C, since a charged battery will inevitably catch fire at this point, reaching temperatures of 600°C or more. If you need an insulator which would withstand a catastrophic battery failure, you should put your battery in a hot-stop bag.